# Integer $p$-norm minimzation

Tags: optimization, normed-spaces, maxima-minima, integers

Suppose that,
$$ x^*=\underset{x\in\Bbb{Z}}{\operatorname{argmin}} \left \{ \Vert{x-a}\Vert_p \right\},$$

where $a \in \Bbb{Z}^n_+$ and,

$$ \Vert{x-a}\Vert_p=\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n} \vert{x - a_i}\vert^p\right)^{1/p}.$$

Can we say that $x^*$ is equal to the median of set $\left \{ a_i , \; \forall i \in 1..n\right \}$? If yes, is there any chance to prove it?

Comment: Regardless of the value of p, the solution to the problem as stated is $x^* =$  vector of zeros Are these some unstated constraints (other than $x$ being integer)?

Comment: @Mark L. Stone: Can you clarify a bit?

Comment: The minimum possible value of a norm is zero. That is achieved using x = vector of zeros, which is a feasible solution (because it is all integer, and there are not other constraints specified). So that is the optimum.  I'm guessing you really have a different problem in mind, so you need to do a better job telling us what that problem is.

Comment: @MarkL.Stone: As you suggested, I revised the problem. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: This still doesn't seem to make sense. Presuming $a = (a_1,...,a_n)$, the optimal solution is $x_i^* = a_i$ for i = 1...n. Perhaps you are trying to be toi fancy with and getting tripped up by your notation.  Show us an example small problem with actual numbers and show what you believe the optimal solution is.

Comment: @MarkL.Stone: Thank you very much. I needed to be more careful about the problem statement. I believe that the current form is now correct. Variable $x$ is not vector; it is a single variable.

Answer (score 0):

This is true for p = 1 (I leave the proof as an elementary exercise for you), but false in general for p > 1.

Consider the following example:
a= (1 2 3 4 10).

Then the optimal x is respectively 3, 4, and 5 for p = 1, 2, and infinity.

Comment: Thanks. Do you have any reference for the proof of $p=1$?

Comment: I suppose it might be somewhere, but I don;t have a reference.